# how to pass a string value into COUNTIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, copy-paste, spreadsheet, countif

For [this](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"jim")
```

how can I pass in a variable?  That is, let's say that cell `C11` has the value "jim"; can I then do something like:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,TEXT_VALUE_OF_CELL(C11))
```

for the same result?

Comment: I'm very curious as to why this question received 2 no-comment downvotes. It may not look like a very *good question* to anyone familiar with Excel, but I don't see how it's not a perfectly acceptable *Question*.

Comment: why, thank you, @AlexM.  The more complex question is how to use wildcards, such as something like:  "*C11" with `COUNTIF`, or other pattern matching.

Comment: Sure, that could also be an interesting question, many (many) variants of which likely exist on this stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cell reference acts as a variable:
`=COUNTIF(A1:A10,C11)`