# Simple pattern with Excel COUNTIF to match a substring?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, countif

How do I fix this formula:  `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*jim*")` to match anything containing the sub-string of "jim" but from a **cell**, as: `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,C11)` where cell `C11` contains the text "jim"?

Perhaps another cell to wrap "jim" with asterisks?

(Surely I don't need to define a special function, or resort to Visual Basic?)

see also:

[how to pass a string value into COUNTIF?](https://superuser.com/q/1413204/55747)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/262852

Comment: if your question was answered, be correct and validate the right answer

Answer (score 4):

concat the regex string and the cell string within the formula as such:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*"&C11&"*")
```

let me know if this helped

Comment: that looks right, I won't be able to check for at least a day.  I think that's at least towards a solution, if not the actual solution.  Thanks.

Comment: i just tried it out using madeup names and it appears to be working properly

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `SUMPRODUCT` and `FIND`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(C11,A1:A10))))
```

Comment: how would that relate to `regex` for `string` data?

Comment: No need for regex, this function looks for the presence of whatever string is in cell `C11` we don't care where it is or if there's more text around it, only that it's present. If it's present, `ISNUMBER` returns "True" (1), if not, it returns "False" (0). The `SUMPRODUCT` then adds all the 1s, resulting in a count of all the cells that include the desired string

Comment: ah, I found:  https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary   which adds to your answer.  Makes more sense, and beautifully simple.